# Zend Studio 9 new projects created in ZS don't have all folders

Tags: macos, zend-framework, zend-studio

So I'm starting out with Zend studio. I installed Zen Frameworks, Zend Studio 9.0 and at one point Zend Server CE (but then removed server).

The problem I am seeing is that when I create a project from my Terminal app using zf.sh, the folder structure is correct (application/, docs/, library/, public/, tests/), and is populated with all the default structure (like application/config/application.ini, etc.).

When I try to do the same from within Zend Studio by going to Project -> Zend Tool and typing in a similar command, like "zf create project test1", the project is created, but doesn't have any of the folder infrastructure I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any zf command from within Zend Studio is producing dynamic library errors like: "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _xsltInitGlobals" and "dyld: Symbol not found: _xsltInitGlobals".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Project->Zend Tool` is intended to create projects. It's intended to create elements in projects.
 To create a project `File->New->PHP project` or `->Zend Framework Project`. I think it depends on your version as to exactly which command will be used.

Comment: Thanks, Rocky. Actually, I'm taking the Zend intro class from Zend and they advocate using the zf tool to create projects as opposed to the File menu from within zend studio. Go figure. :)

Comment: is that zend_Tool from the command line? The create project from the file menu should use Zend_Tool in the back ground while creating a project.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling zend server reinstated the ability to generate the proper project template files.
It appears installing zend replaced or changed libphp.so, which was causing the error.